# How to rendering to html in the viewsets in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class MyVideo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default='')
    seotitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default='')
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, default='')
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

serializers.py

```
class MyVideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyVideo
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class My(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyVideo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyVideoSerializer

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer,)
    template_name = "my.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ??????

    def get_query(self):
        # ??????
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('my/', views.My), # ???????? anything wrong here?
]
```

my.html

```
<html><body>
    <h1>My video</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for d in data %}
        <li>{{ d.title }}</li>  # ?????? anything wrong here?
        <li>{{ d.seotitle }}</li>
        <li>{{ d.keywords }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body></html>
```

I have a MyVideo model which store several videos record in the database. What I wanna implement is that to display the information of those videos through the my.html.

e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/my/103 can access the video which id=103, and on this page display its fields (title, seotitle, keywords, etc.).

Any nice implementation or suggestion? Thanks!

**UPDATE

```
<html><body>
<h1>My video</h1>
<ul>
    {{ data }}
</ul>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Where you have inserted `# ????` What do you have there?

Comment: @Lewis Nothing, I don't know how to do next...

Comment: Why do you think you need to define those methods at all?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not sure do I need override those method or not, I just followed [the API docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer) and tried.

Comment: It's the [viewsets docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) you should be reading. You don't need those methods, but you do need a [router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) in the urls.

Comment: @DanielRoseman As your points out, I have already implemented that, but it's only for the restful API and cannot rendering to the HTML page. Any demo for this?

Comment: I am on my mobile cant help much but what i can say My.html is correct , url.py path is missing  you should refer to the my class  in views.py

Comment: @ahmet I thought that my urls.py has already linked the 'my/' path to views.My in views.py

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake you just did not gave a name but its not important so that part is ok as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   from django.shortcuts import render
    class My(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = MyVideo.objects.all()
        serializeddata = MyVideoSerializer(queryset,many=true)

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer,)
    template_name = "my.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render_to_response(template_name, {'data': serializeddata.data})
    #or use below
      #return render(
    #request, 
    #template_name=template_name,
    #{'data': serializeddata}
#)

    def get_query(self):
        # ??????
```

**UPDATE**

models.py

```
"""
Definition of models.
"""

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class MyVideo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default='')
    seotitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default='')
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, default='')
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from app.models import MyVideo

class MyVideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyVideo
        fields = '__all__'
```

my.html

```
<html><body>
    <h1>My video</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for d in data %}
        <li>Title: {{ d.title }}</li>  
        <li>SEO Title:{{ d.seotitle }}</li>
        <li>KeyWords {{ d.keywords }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body></html>
```

views.py

```
def my(request):
    """Renders the contact page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    queryset = MyVideo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyVideoSerializer(queryset,many=True)
    #datan = {"title":"Test Title"}
    return render(
        request,
        'app/my.html',
        {
            'data':serializer_class.data,
        }
    )
```

NOTE: You can add if(request.method == GET): elif(request.method == POST)

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Let me Know if Any Issue Arrives!

Comment: "'My' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method." You changed the original serializer_class which brings this error. Any ideas?

Comment: I added "serializer_class = MyVideoSerializer" back and it runs. However, the "{'data': serializeddata} didn't rendered to the HTML page, but it returns the data if I just print(serializeddata) in the code.

Comment: My mistake, make it serializeddata.data and let me know the result!

Comment: serializeddata = MyVideoSerializer(queryset, many=true) also do it like this as the result may be many!

Comment: Things become better...All the data that I need can be print out in the console with "print(serializeddata.data)". However, the my.html still only display the h1 title "My video" and blank under that. Do you think anything wrong that I made in the HTML code?

Comment: Can you share an image of the current output of print(serializeddata.data) and share the code of your serializer so that i can understand the issue in depth. Alsoif the answer helped, do vote 

Comment: I thought the serializers.py has already been attached above. the output like this: [OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('title', 'slide 1'), ('url', ''), ('local_banner', '/media/images/slide/2018/07/29/zhouxing02.jpg'), ('priority', 5), ('upload_time', '2018-06-21T14:54:12.956598+08:00')]), OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('title', 'slide 2'), ('url', ''), ('local_banner', None), ('priority', 2), ('upload_time', '2018-06-21T14:54:24.160807+08:00')]), OrderedDict([('id', 3), ('title', 'slide 3'), ('url', ''), ('local_banner', None), ('priority', 3), ('upload_time', '2018-06-21T14:54:30.178998+08:00')])]

Comment: OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('title', 'slide 1'), ('url', ''), ('local_banner', '/media/images/slide/2018/07/29/zhouxing02.jpg'), ('priority', 5), ('upload_time', '2018-06-21T14:54:12.956598+08:00')]),

see this Individual, it only has the title attribute and no seotitle and keywords attribute that is why, You need changes in your serializer.
class MyVideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyVideo
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'seotitle','keywords','status')

Comment: But even I changed the my.html as shown in UPDATE above, only {{ data }} in it. Still nothing...

Comment: Try the Above if it does not resolves, let me know, i would update a code in working format by running and testing it myself. I am enroute to Office so would do it there but do try the above requested change in serializer

Comment: Actually, you can see, in the MyVideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) I set the fields = '__all__', that will not missing anything. Hope you can help if you have time. thx!

Comment: @mrhaoji I updated the Code with an Output Result. Kindly See it!

Comment: I works nice here! BTW, what if I wanna get a specific record? e.g. right now url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/my/, I wanna http://127.0.0.1:8000/my/103/ to access the #133 record in MyVideo model. Should I add a parameter to the method, like this "def my(request, pk):"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177324/discussion-between-mrhaoji-and-syed-faizan).

Comment: You would need to Add a new URL and define a new View suppose MyId(request,id)
url(r'^my/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.MyId),
And then get the Object based on the Id!